# mongoDB - How to find and sort multiple fields in several documents and store them in a single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

The header describes the problem well I think. I have a collection named "results" with serveral documents:

```
{
    "_id" : "item_e4a2086048057ac9",
    "home" : "FH>87218379012",
    "username:" : "Jon Doe",
    "Apps" : {
        "game" : {
            "InVals" : {
                "ET" : {
                    "et1" : 1,
                    "et2" : 88,
                    "et3" : 7,
                    "et4" : 0.68,
                    "et5" : 5253,
                    "et6" : "7233-AL",
                    "et7" : "23-PL",
                    "et8" : "791-GY"
                }
            },
            "OutVals" : {
                "ET" : 74.00
            }
        }
    },
    "PAT" : 74
}
```

Second document:

```
{
    "_id" : "item_a90a2086048057ac9",
    "home" : "FH>87218379012",
    "username:" : "Jon Doe2",
    "Apps" : {
        "game" : {
            "InVals" : {
                "ET" : {
                    "et1" : 0,
                    "et2" : 9,
                    "et3" : 96,
                    "et4" : 3218,
                    "et5" : 6,
                    "et6" : "65-AL",
                    "et7" : "265-PL",
                    "et8" : "4-GY"
                }
            },
            "OutVals" : {
                "ET" : 4.00
            }
        }
    },
    "PAT" : 4
}
```

And so on...
Now I need to query all "PAT"-fields in the specific documents, where the field "home" is equal to "FH>87218379012", than sort them in descending order and store them in a variable which is an array:

```
var resultsArray = [74, 4....,n];
```

It would also be ok if there is an solution, where I have to store each "PAT"-Value in a single variable, sort them and save them in an array later. At the end I just need to have all "PAT" values of the documents which have "FH>87218379012" as "home" in descended order in an array.

Is that possible or do I have to change something in my collection?

Comment: What are you actually expecting here? The short fragment suggests you want to "sort" the values present in `"OutVals"` of every document. How may documents? Where do you need to "sort" them? Does this require "paging" of results, or is it simply a small set of data where you want to work with these values returned in order?

Comment: Ok, maybe I should specifiy what I want to do. So, the "PAT"-Value or "ET" in OutVals (same) is stored in the above structure in every document in the collection "results". I need to get every "PAT" out of every document which has "FH>87218379012" in "home", because I need to visualize these values of every "home" in a bar chart in descending order. In this case starting at 74, than 4, that 3rd highest etc. Because the bar chart reads the input in this structure [74, 4...], I thought about saving the query data from the db in var resultsArray = [...].

Comment: Saving it where? Your comment below does not exactly inspire faith that you even understand the environment in which the query needs to run. All you are really asking for is "one value" out of each document returned, which is fairly simple. Which library are you using to connect to MongoDB?

Comment: I am using Meteor Blaze. Yes, I am new to mongoDB and just want to get data out of it, and visualize the data in a bar chart.

Comment: So you want `resultsArray = collection.find({home: "FH>87218379012"}, {fields: {"PAT": 1}}).fetch().map( d => d.PAT );` Where `collection` is whatever your meteor collection name is in the current scope. You can then either `.sort()` the retrieval as `collection.find({home: "FH>87218379012"}, {fields: {"PAT": 1}, sort: { "PAT": -1 }).fetch()` or apply a regular JavaScript `.sort()` on the resulting array

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. There is a little typo I think. The last "}" after the sort operator, but after fixing that, it works perfectly. Sorry for my confusing question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to match your `PAT` value, sort by that field and add a [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the values to an array :

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        home: "FH>87218379012"
    }
}, {
    $sort: { PAT: -1 }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        result: {
            $push: "$PAT"
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thank you, but although this sounds pretty logical, I get the error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: db is not defined` when I paste your command into the chrome browser console. I also read through the docs of "aggregate" and the command is written like you did: `db.results.aggregate`. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Jaybruh What you are doing wrong is *"pasting into the chrome browser console"*. This is not code that you run in a browser.